# Preference for rows where field is different from "x"

Tags: mysql

I want to query my database so that I don't **order by** or **order by desc** but instead seek rows when a given field is different from 0 first and only after get others **ordered by** if there are no rows with field != "0". What is the best way to accomplish this or even is it possible to do so?

This is supposing the field can have values from -100 to 0 to  100

With example:

Considering **LIMIT** equals 3 and field in consideration is **field1**

**field1**

10

0

-20

-40

Another set:

**field1**

0

0

-100

50

In the first set, the results extracted will be **10, -20 and -40** (by any order), while in the second set they should be **-100, 50 and 0** (any of the zeros, by any order).
First I'd like to check whether there exists != 0 in the database and if **true** extract those and only after 0's until I fill the **LIMIT**

Comment: `order by yourfield <> 0, field = x, field ASC`? You can order by arbitrary values, including derived/boolean values.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you provide some example input and output data?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
its not clear **AT ALL** what you want so I'm only guessing here.

`I want to query my database so that I don't order by or order by desc but instead seek rows when a given field is different from 0`

seek rows to me means find all rows that are not 0.

`only after get others ordered by if there are no rows with field != "0".`

to me that means order the rows in a sub query where the field is not 0.

with that in mind maybe this query?

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE field IN (
    SELECT field 
    from table t
    WHERE field <> 0 
    ORDER BY field
)
```

without data It's not clear what you want. but i think something like this is what you were asking.. you could also try

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE field <> 0
ORDER BY field
```

Comment: @Namezito where are these sets from field1 coming from? two separate tables?

Comment: no, they are just two hypothetical situations for the same table. Field1 is the field of interest to seek/order by

Comment: @Namezito so are you trying to find the last 0 in the field and then get the rows after that that fill your limit? still confused sorry